# sqlite, how can I match a pattern held in a field rather than precoded txt in select clause? (without installing a regexpr function)

Tags: sqlite

I have a log file of shell commands issued and also a trim list of commands I can delete as they are not of long term interest.
At present I do the deletes by matching a fixed set of patterns I code in my sql around the basic command text in my trim list. i.e.
delete... where cmd like '% '|| removableCmdPattern||' %'...

I'd like to see if I can specify my patterns in the trim list for more flexibility & specificity.
I've added a few such patterns to try this out...

First show the relevant select from the trim list

Then use that data in a select from the log - which returns nothing as the wildcards in the field are not implemented as wildcards.

If I issue the command as a text pattern then the statement "compiles" the wildcards into the query and I see the relevant data.

```
sqlite> SELECT * from trimList where removableCmdPattern like "%\%%" ESCAPE "\";
removableCmdPattern
-------------------
ls %
% ls %
sqlite> select * from history where cmd like (SELECT * from trimList where removableCmdPattern like "%\%%" ESCAPE "\");
sqlite> select * from history where cmd like "% ls %";
id          salt        timestamp            user        tty         wdID        cmd
----------  ----------  -------------------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------------------------------------------------------------
22960       1           2017-09-11 10:09:39  colinwin    ttys007     NULL           ttys007 1505120979 find ~/Dropbox -type l -exec ls -lah {} \;
27183       1           2017-09-11 10:09:39  colinwin    ttys002     NULL           ttys002 1505120979 find ~/Dropbox -type l -exec ls -lah {} \;
36686       1           2017-09-11 10:09:39  colinwin    ttys003     NULL           ttys003 1505120979 find ~/Dropbox -type l -exec ls -lah {} \;
39511       1           2020-11-08 17:32:06  colinwin    ttys003     NULL           ttys003 1604856726 find . -name video_info* -exec ls -al {} \
39636       1           2020-11-15 17:37:29  colinwin    ttys003     NULL           ttys003 1605461849 function lse() { find ${1:-.} -perm +111 -
39637       1           2020-11-15 17:38:23  colinwin    ttys003     NULL           ttys003 1605461903 function lse() { find ${1:-.} -perm +111 -
```

I guess I could select various forms of patterns from the trim list and then select statement with the same wildcards as text. i.e. find trim items like "% text %" and then find cmd like '% '||substr(trimpattern...)||' %' but this is spaghetti inducing, limited, messy, clunky and inefficient.

Any ideas or some trick I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using exists like:

```
select * from history where exists(
   SELECT null from trimList 
   where removableCmdPattern like "%\%%" ESCAPE "\" and 
      cmd like removableCmdPattern);
```

Comment: Don't know why I convinced myself patterns in fields were not used, in fact I can find all sorts of ways of matching to patterns in fields. I think I was careless with the substrings and matches I was looking at... Thanks!